# Persist form data values in single page application

Tags: single-page-application, singlepage, durandal

I have 2 views in my SPA built up using durandal. I have a form (consider basic employee information form) in the first view. Also, I am having a button in the view called "upload" which routes to a different view to upload some documents. Once user finishes uploading, it redirects back to my first view and when it does, the first view reloads (renders) again loosing all my previously entered values. Same is the case when I press browser back button on my second view (the upload page).

Any solution on how I can persist data in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Posting code would make it a bit easier but I would think you'd need to maybe store what's entered in LocalStorage or something and then retrieve it later?

[AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/) can make this easier.